# Можно ли писать браузерные приложения на java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, swing

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли реализовать приложение в браузере на java без перезагрузки страницы, или это можно сделать только на js. Например написать чат на swing и как то отобразить его в браузере, или браузерную игрушку!

Comment: Ну что-то такое сделать можно. Во-первых есть джава апплеты. Во-вторых есть gwt, это "давайте писать javascript код на java". Но на практике это мягко говоря не очень удобные технологии

Comment: Посмотрите Vaadin.

Comment: JavaFX + WebView - это Вы свой браузер можете написать. А для собственно "приложения в браузере" - используйте возможности JS + HTML5 и CSS3. Хороший REST API на бэке и грамотный фронт - вот и человеческое приложение.

Answer (score 4):

Из более-менее актуальных решений - только **GWT** (Google Web Toolkit), на нем все еще пишутся хорошие "Single Page Apps" в браузере. Java FX и тем более Java Applets уже потеряли свою популярность.

Google Chrome перестал поддерживать Java Applets (http://www.java.com/ru/download/faq/chrome.xml).

В целом, я бы не советовал ни одно из этих решений и выбрал связку из **React**/**Angular**/ или другого популярного фреймворка + **JS (ES6 + Babel)/Typescript** как язык разработки.